# load keras h5 model and then specify encoder and generator

Tags: keras, load

I load trained keras vae model

```
Model = tf.keras.models.load_model('models/vae_lstm.h5', custom_objects={'CustomVariationalLayer': CustomVariationalLayer, 'zero_loss': zero_loss, 'kl_loss':kl_loss})
```

and then specify encoder and generator

```
# build a model to project inputs on the latent space
encoder = Model(x, z_mean)
#encoder.save('models/encoder32dim512hid30kvocab_loss29_val34.h5')

# build a generator that can sample from the learned distribution
decoder_input = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
_h_decoded = decoder_h(repeated_context(decoder_input))
_x_decoded_mean = decoder_mean(_h_decoded)
_x_decoded_mean = Activation('softmax')(_x_decoded_mean)
generator = Model(decoder_input, _x_decoded_mean)
```

and test on some data

```
#test on a validation sentence
sent_idx = 100
sent_encoded = encoder.predict(data_val[sent_idx:sent_idx+2,:])
x_test_reconstructed = generator.predict(sent_encoded, batch_size = 1)
reconstructed_indexes = np.apply_along_axis(np.argmax, 1, x_test_reconstructed[0])
#np.apply_along_axis(np.max, 1, x_test_reconstructed[0])
#np.max(np.apply_along_axis(np.max, 1, x_test_reconstructed[0]))
word_list = list(np.vectorize(vocp.index2word.get)(reconstructed_indexes))
print(' '.join(word_list))
original_sent = list(np.vectorize(vocp.index2word.get)(data_val[sent_idx]))
print(' '.join(original_sent))
```

but the result is different from when I tested the same data right after training the vae model.

here is the entire code
https://github.com/NicGian/text_VAE/blob/master/text_VAE_v18.ipynb

What's the problem with the code?
Should I save the encoder and generator regardless of saving the entire model?